# Compare values in column A and B then paste values in both columns into column C and values in B but not A into column D

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA coding. I'm self-taught but usually resort to looking up code for simple things because it's a whole different language that I am not at all fluent in. I have a macro that obtains values from the PCOMM application and puts them into column A. I then paste values for comparison into column B. Where I'm stuck is trying to locate values present in both column A and B and pasting them into column C. I also want to do the reverse in column D; paste values that are in column B but NOT in column A. I don't even know where to start. This is for work so I had to blur some things out.

I don't know where to begin so I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my smartphone, so i can't test it. Once data have been pasted, try this:

```
Sub SubFilter()
    
    Dim RngCell as Range
    Dim RngResult01 as Range
    Dim RngResult02 as Range
    
    Set RngCell = Range("B2") '<First cell with data in column B
    Set RngResult01 = Range("C2")
    Set RngResult02 = Range("D2")
    
    Do Until RngCell.Value2 = ""
        
        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), RngCell.Value2) > 0 Then
            
            RngResult01.Value2 = RngCell.Value2
            
            Set RngResult01 = RngResult01.Offset(1, 0)
            
        Else
            
            RngResult02.Value2 = RngCell.Value2
            
            Set RngResult02 = RngResult02.Offset(1, 0)
            
        End if
        
        Set RngCell = RngCell.Offset(1, 0)
        
    Loop

End Sub
```